# Is travelling through all central Asian countries (Turkmenistan, Uzbekistan and Kyrgyzstan) possible only with transit visas?

Tags: chinese-citizens, azerbaijan, kyrgyzstan, uzbekistan, turkmenistan

I'm a Chinese national, living in Belgium right now.  I am thinking of departing from Azerbaijan, then taking a ferry to Turkmenistan, then Uzbekistan and maybe Kyrgyzstan, finally arrive in China.(within central Asian countries preferrablly by train)

For all the countries I would pass through, do I need a normal tourist visa or a transit visa?

Comment: At least for Turkmenistan getting a transit visa is pretty much the easiest way of visiting the country.

Comment: Also why not Tajikistan? It's fantastic! :D Go up the Pamir Highway (M41) into Kyrgyzstan, and then exit to China.

Comment: Thanks guys! Mark, Tajikistan sounds also cool! How's their train system, I can't handle long road trip since I have a bad car sick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really.  For example, [Uzbekistan has a 2x72hr transit visa](http://caravanistan.com/visa/uzbekistan/), but that really doesn't give you time to do much at all. You need to get a tourist visa, and a Letter of Invitation.

It's probably the hardest one to get (although Kazakhstan took me a long time when I was in St Petersburg).

The 'best' resource online for this at present is probably [Caravanistan](http://caravanistan.com) for those countries.  They'll tell you exactly what the latest visa requirements are, but essentially, no.  That Turkmenistan ferry is notorious for example, for not leaving on time - sometimes waiting a week before it departs, which makes it very, very hard to plan visas around, and would certainly cause you problems even if you could get a 'transit' visa that allowed you to use the ferry.

Comment: Thanks! I do hear ferry to Turkmenistan is at least easier than the one to Kazakhstan. The tourism visa is costly,though. Which countries in central asia have u been to? All with tourism visa?

Comment: I went to Kazakhstan (twice), Uzbekistan, Kyrgyzstan and Tajikistan.  User @peter-hahndorf has also been to a few. I needed visas for all, and a LOI for Uzbekistan.  Was able to get visas on the ground for most as well, as I went.  If you want to discuss, do leave a msg for me in the [chat] :)

Comment: According to the Uzbek embassy, a transit visa still requires the letters of invitation: http://www.uzbekistan.be/visa%20regulations.html

Answer (score 5):

A great resource for this can be found at [Visa requirements for Chinese citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Chinese_citizens) (Wikipedia has a page like this for every country). On this page, you can see that although Chinese citizens do not need a visa for Azerbaijan to visit up to 30 days, a visa is required for all the other countries on your proposed itinerary.

Similarly, you can find additional information on the following pages:

- [Visa policy of Turkmenistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Turkmenistan)
- [Visa policy of Uzbekistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Uzbekistan)
- [Visa policy of Kyrgyzstan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Kyrgyzstan)

The only one where a transit type visa is mentioned at all is Turkmenistan, where:

> Citizens of all countries have the right to visa-free transit through the international transit area of the Ashgabat Airport.